# Sublime paste in snippet

Tags: sublime-text-2, clipboard, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, snippets

I have got a sublime snippet to get console.log in js who look like that :

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log('$1', $1);]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log()</description>
</snippet>
```

I type `cl` `tab` and `cmd+v` and I got what i want.

What i really would like is to `cl` `tab`and have the content of my clipboard inside the `$1`.

For the moment I have a small improvement:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log('$TM_CURRENT_WORD', $TM_CURRENT_WORD);]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log()</description>
</snippet>
```

Which do the same but insert the word after the cursor when I hit tab.

Do someone have an idea to get the content of the clipboard inside the parameters? Or have a nice console.log snippet?

Thanks

@xavhan

Answer (score 0):

Set up your snippet to use the currently selected text, and use a keyboard shortcut to trigger its usage instead of using a tabTrigger.

`<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log('$SELECTION', $SELECTION);]]></content>
    <!-- <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger> -->
    <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log()</description>
</snippet>`

`{ 
        "keys": ["alt+z"], 
        "command": "insert_snippet", 
        "args": { "name": "Packages/User/snippets/console.sublime-snippet" } 
    }`